# Como listar todos arquivos no formato ".ts" de pastas e subpastas para ser convertidos para ".avi"?

Tags: linux, shell-script

Encontrei um shell-script e modifiquei ele para atender minha necessidade e ficou assim:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$1" ] && cd "$1"

ls -1 *.TS
[ "$?" -ne 0 ] && echo 'Sem arquivos TS nesse diretório' && exit 0
for ARQUIVO in $(ls -1 *.TS)
do
ARQ_DESTINO="${ARQUIVO%%.TS}.avi"
echo "Convertendo $ARQUIVO para $ARQ_DESTINO"

ffmpeg -i "$ARQUIVO" -vcodec libxvid -b 2000k \
-acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 128k "$ARQ_DESTINO"
done
```

Só que eu não sei como fazer para esse script entrar nos subdiretórios e pegue cada arquivo `.ts` e converta para `.avi`, nesse caso ai acima ele só faz no diretório em que o script está.

Como posso fazer com esse script para fazer esse processo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez seja mais apropriado usar o [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) para essa tarefa:

```
find . -name "*.TS" | while read -r ARQUIVO; do
  ARQ_DESTINO="${ARQUIVO%%.TS}.avi"
  echo "Convertendo $ARQUIVO para $ARQ_DESTINO"
  #....   
done
```

O ponto `.` indica o diretório atual, a busca inicia-se a partir dele.

Comment: Ficou assim: `#!/bin/bash
[ "$1" ] && cd "$1"
find . -name "*.TS" | while read -r ARQUIVO; 
do
  ARQ_DESTINO="${ARQUIVO%%.TS}.avi"
  echo "Convertendo $ARQUIVO para $ARQ_DESTINO"
  ffmpeg -i "$ARQUIVO" -vcodec libxvid -b 2000k \
   -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 128k "$ARQ_DESTINO"
done`.
Mais não deu certo na execução.
Eu acho que meu código tem algum erro só pode. 
Retorna esse erro: `Enter command: <target>|all <time>|-1 <command>[ <argument>]
Parse error, at least 3 arguments were expected, only 1 given in string `

Comment: @JB_ Na linha do `ffmpeg` adicione no final `< /dev/null`, por exemplo: `ffmpeg ... -ab 128k "$ARQ_DESTINO" < /dev/null`

Comment: Muito bom,
deu certo.
Solucionado o problema. < /dev/null foi a solução final.
Obrigado.